# How do I freeze an AR scene in ARKit and then restore the scene elsewhere - Swift, XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I have an AR scene (built as a node with children nodes) that I want the user to walk inside it.
Because it can be large, I added a pause button in the corner so that if the user hits an obstacle in the real world, he'll just need to press-and-hold that button to freeze the scene, move elsewhere in the real world, and when the button will be released the scene would have moved as-is to that new location, retaining the same relative position and rotation inside that scene.

What I did is very simple.  When button is touched down I just did:

```
sceneView.session.pause()
```

And when the button is Touch Up Inside I ran:

```
sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

This seemed to do the trick.
However, after I clicked and moved once or twice more and moved back to where I was before, my whole AR scene suddenly jumped back to its previous location in the real world.  So it did freeze and showed up in the new location for a second or two, but then it jumped back.

I tried to resume the session with several of the available options.
If I ran:

```
sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking])
```

the whole scene would move to the new location, but it would be set to its initial position and rotation as if I was standing at (0,0,0) when I started the app, but now moved to the new location.  In other words, it lost the current location and rotation that I was at when I pressed the pause button and just reset the scene.

All the other options that I tried had the same effect as if I didn't add any options.

I should add that I'm not using any anchors (so far) nor any ray casting.
I didn't try different combinations of those options (except removeExistingAnchors and resetTracking together), but I doubt that that would help.  Am I wrong?

What am I doing wrong?
Anyone have a solution for my problem?
Or will I need to manually record the current position and rotation when pressing the pause button and then restore those with some position change of the node?  I was hoping I could skip having to do it this way.
And if I do need to do it manually, any tips on how to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!